# Show and delay - jQuery, how use delay?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delay, show, slide

I have some problem with show and delay..
When I try add .delay to show function everything is wrong...
Do you have any solutions how can I delaying function .show ?
I looking for solutions on jQuery site but I wasn't find answer...

This function should be delaying:

```
$('#content').show("slide", { direction: "right", duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutCirc' }, hideLoader());
```

Comment: `show("slide"` have no duration and easing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delay()` only works on animations which are queued on the element - which `show()` is not. Instead use `setTimeout` to run your function after a specified delay:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#content').show("slide", { direction: "right", duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutCirc' }, hideLoader());
}, 2000); // 2000ms = 2 seconds
```

Comment: OK, it works fine.. but I have one problem more.. I using jScrollPane for new content with livequery.  `$(function() {
 $('.content_all').livequery(function() { 
 $(this).jScrollPane();
 });
});`  Because new content is delaying jScrollPane isin't initalizing, when I delay jScrollPane, first new content is loading fine, but next is wrong - jScrollPane isint loading..